# jQuery filer theme css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [jFiler](http://filer.grandesign.md/) for ajax upload of files, and I am trying to change the theme css to have both input box and item boxes inline in the same row something similar like the code below, just to show you an example of inline boxes in a row, or maybe in a carousel together where input box would be fixed on either left or right side of the row, and uploaded items would append next to it:

```
   <div class="floating-box">Input box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Uploaded Item1 box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Uploaded Item2 box</div>
```

Css:

```
.floating-box {
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 75px;
margin: 10px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
```

and not input box above the item boxes like it is by default. I have tried changing their css, but I haven't figured out how to do that, if anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: can you show us a sample page or fiddle?

Comment: I am sorry for the off comment, but @Obi-WanSpock can't resist not to compliment how awesome your username is